# Maven assembly plugin produces undeployable war file

Tags: deployment, packaging, war, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm working on a multi module project using Spring, Hibernate, GWT and Maven 3 and try to deploy a war-file distribution to a servlet container (preferably Tomcat 7 or Jetty 8). I create the war-file using maven-assembly-plugin 2.2.1 (I'm running maven 3). During the maven build everything works perfectly and the distribution archive is created.

But when I try to deploy the war file, I get ClassNotFound-Exceptions (e.g. Spring ContextLoaderListener and the like) although everything is in place (Web-inf/lib etc. pp.). So, the webapp isn't starting. Then I unpack the war-file into the servlet containers webapp directory and everything is working fine... ??

After further investigation I came across the following thing: 
If I take an arbitrary war file A' created by maven-war-plugin (!), replace its content with the unpacked content from the war file I created using maven-assembly-plugin (let me call it 
A.) I can see two things happen:

1. the resulting war file A' is a few bytes smaller than my original file A although their content is identical
2. the deployment of A' suddenly works like a charm

This is weird and I have absolutely no idea what's happening. Maybe there is an issue and maven-war-plugin and maven-assembly-plugin handle war file packaging differently?! I mean, a war is only a renamed zip file with some predefined structure... Maybe it has absolutely nothing to do with maven but with file encoding or other things? Any ideas on this? I appreciate any hint, that could help me in investigating this...

This is my assembly descriptor

```
<assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>dist</id>
<formats>
    <format>war</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <includes>
            <include>mypackage.client:parametermgmt:*</include>
            <include>mypackage.static:client:*</include>
        </includes>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact> 
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory> 
    </dependencySet>

    <dependencySet>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
        <includes>
            <include>mypackage.server.database:domain:*</include>
            <include>mypackage.server.businessobjects:BOdomain:*</include>
            <include>mypackage.server.security:security:*</include>
            <include>mypackage.server.services:paramgmt:*</include>
        </includes>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>    
        <outputDirectory>Web-inf/lib</outputDirectory>   
    </dependencySet>

    <dependencySet>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <includes>
            <include>mypackage.static:server:*</include>
        </includes>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact> 
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory> 
    </dependencySet>

    <dependencySet>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
        <includes>
            <include>*</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>mypackage.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <outputDirectory>Web-inf/lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>

</dependencySets>
```

Answer (score -2):

The maven-assembly-plugin is not intended to create a war. For this purpose use the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) instead.

If you need to create war files for different environments like test,qa, production. This can be used as well a base for different app servers. But if we are talking about a application server this means we should create ear files instead of war files (This means to use maven-ear-plugin instead of maven-war-plugin).

```
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   |-- java
    |   |-- resources
    |   |-- environment
    |   |   |-- test
    |   |   |   `-- database.properties
    |   |   |-- qa
    |   |   |   `-- database.properties
    |   |   `-- production
    |   |       `-- database.properties
    |   `-- webapp
```

You need the following assembly for that (for every environment) which can be created based on this as a template:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

  <id>test</id>
  <formats>
    <format>war</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <outputDirectory>WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/environment/test/</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

To support different artifacts for different environments this is the time for the maven-assembly-plugin like this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/test.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>qa</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/qa.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>production</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/production.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

The result is creating three different war files which can be distinguished by their appropriate classifier with a single call ([detailed description can be read here](http://blog.soebes.de/index.php?/archives/340-Maven-Configuration-For-Multipe-Environments.html)):

```
mvn clean package
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. The assembly plugin can be used to [produce war files as it can be used to produce zip, dir, tar.gz and other formats.](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies-sect-descriptor.html) I tend to use it besides the war plugin because I want a fine grained control over the assembly process and the final war contents. Another option would be to use war oyerlays but unfortunately this did not work for me because all dependent-war content outside Web-inf/classes is omitted i.e. getting lost while the dependent wars are being unpacked. Maybe I'm missing someth

Comment: If it isn't intended to create a war then why does it provide that as a supported format?

Comment: If you want to produce different wars for different app servers how could you achive this with maven-war-plugin?

Comment: @ChristopherHunt The format is more or less only the extension of the file not really the format. Cause if you like to create a war file you need to create a particular folder/file structure. You can create a zip file with the same content and just rename the zip file to a war. That's it.